# Making Django query if my class consists of a function? How do make a query which will return the sum of available_count for a particular device

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-class-based-views, django-filter

```
class Magazine(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(RUDevice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False, 
        related_name='ru_magazine', help_text="Select Device for magazine")
    magazine_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Magazine Number"), default=0, 
        help_text='Magazine number for selected Remote Unit')
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, 
        blank=False, related_name='magazine_product_type', help_text="Select product type")
    max_capacity = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Maximum Capacity"),  default=0, 
        help_text='Select Maximum Capacity')
 


    def available_count(self):
        /*some code*/
        return available_product
```

I have tried:
Magazine.objects.filter(device='some_device').aggregate(sum=Sum('available_count()')['sum']

Comment: that won't work. You need to share the logic for available_product, which can be translated into a query

Comment: The function available_count() have multiple dependencies as this is part of a bigger project. Is it possible to directly call this function while writing query set? if there are any guidelines, can you provide me any documentation?